# Which way is better for MySQL connection string?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# program that connect to MySQL database. My original connectionString is embedded in code like below

```
public class RemoteDatabaseConnection
{
    private MySqlConnection remoteConnect;
    private string conStr;
    
    public RemoteDatabaseConnection()
    {
        conStr = "server=" + AppSetting.serverIP + ";user id=ABCD;password=XYZERT;Database=" + AppSetting.databaseName;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            remoteConnect = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connect Failed\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Appsetting.serverIP and AppSetting.databaseName are loaded from ini file and it can be changed.

But I found someone use connectionString in app.config. like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conStr" connectionString="server=192.168.0.245;user id=ABCD;password=XYZERT;Database=service_report"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Can anyone explain which way is better and secure?

If I want to use connectionString in app.config, how can it become like conStr = "server=" + AppSetting.serverIP + ";user id=ABCD;password=XYZERT;Database=" + AppSetting.databaseName;" ? Because my serverIP and databaseName is not fixed.

Comment: Hard-coding the username and password is always a bad idea. You can easily change the configuration settings, and even encrypt them. `my serverIP and databaseName is not fixed.` what does that mean? Will the server change every time you run the application, or even while the application is running?

Comment: BTW that `RemoteDatabaseConnection` class is a deadlock waiting to happen. It offers no benefit over ADO.NET's connection classes and *no* way to dispose the connection. Connections should be short-lived, declared in a `using` block so they're disposed immediately after use. This way, any remaining locks and resources on the server are released. ADO.NET uses connection pooling to make opening a new connection cheap.

Comment: If you want to make your code work with different database products use the abstract base classes, eg DbConnection, DbCommand instead of concrete classes like MySqlConnection or SqlServerConnection. You can also use the [DB Provider model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) to specify even the database product through configuration.

Comment: "my serverIP and databaseName is not fixed" mean I use this program in different place, so maybe this factory ip is 211.220.123.22, next factory ip is 123.222.52.43. But i don't know the ip address when I coding.

Comment: In that case you can store different settings in `app.config` on each machine. All these things are described in the ADO.NET tutorials, books and courses. Don't try to guess your way around. This class alone would cause serious performance problems *for the database*, not just the app. If you concatenate strings to create queries at another point you'll allow SQL injection attacks

Comment: Is it possible to use variable in app.config? Because this program may have many different server ip to connect.

Comment: You just said each installation only connects to a single server. What *do* you want after all? You can edit `app.config` after deployment. You can't edit the code

Comment: This program is install on different place, Each place has their own server and their database name. So I make a INI file to store server ip and let user to change to their ip on INI file. So if I use app.config for connectionSting. I want to know how can I use the variable in app.config.

Comment: Don't make an `ini` file. You already have one, it's `app.config`. You don't need any variables when the settings don't change at runtime

Comment: Yes. I want o move it to app.config, but the question is server ip is not fixed, it change everytime when this program installed on new place.

Comment: Which is no problem at all - use a different setting in app.config. That's what you do with `ini` isn't it? Change the value in `app.config`. Again, this is explained in docs, tutorials and courses. By trying to guess how things work you're spending a *lot* more time than just reading the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole documentation discussing this topic.
[Official microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Another thing is that I don`t think there is a scenario that embedding connection string directly in the code is good practice. Even though you hide your server IP and database name you expose your user id and your db password, which can go badly. The most secure way of storing secrets is either in .env, app.config or store it in some sort of cloud service such as Azure Key vault. [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Entity Framework Core you can be used like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, 
     you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 
     for guidance on storing connection strings.
     
   optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=library;user=user;password=password");
}
```

And it's better to store ConnectionString in appconfig.json.
You can set this on **ConfigureServices** in **Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")));
```

See this link for more help:

[mySQL.com help Entity Framework Core Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)

[mySQL.com help Creating a Connector/NET Connection String](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html)